# use few button and other widget in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, widget, fragment, onclicklistener

I want to use a few `Button`, `Spinner` and `TextView` on fragmets but i don't know how to do that since i was newbie in android programming.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

here's my java activity

```
package com.elvis.triagetags;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class formActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

and this my form.layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="428dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/header"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/fullname"
            android:textColor="#0000CD"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etIden"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Gen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/gen"
            android:textColor="#0000CD"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinGen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="#0000CD"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etdate"
                android:layout_width="0.99dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/wp_button"
                android:text="@string/date1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="148dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.87"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pop"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/urlImage"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/capture_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/wp_button"
            android:text="@string/capture" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/wp_button"
            android:text="@string/bt" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/elvis"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example to show you how to do:

```
package com.elvis.triagetags;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class formActivity extends Fragment {
  Button btnDate;
  Button btnCapture;
  Spinner spinGen;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form, container, false);
    btnCapture = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.capture_button);
    btnDate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    spinGen = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinGen);
    spinGen.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerGen());
    btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //...   
        }
    });
    //...
    return rootView;
}
}


public class SpinnerGen implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

follow this [link](http://android-app-project.blogspot.com/2013/12/android-actionbarsherlock-sliding-menu.html), you will find a good example